# Key bindings with multiple keys

Tags: java, swing, combinations, key-bindings

I'm using this code to bind keyboard keys to custom actions without using the `KeyListener`:

```
Action left = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed left key");
    }
};

Action right = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed right key");
    }
};

Action space = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("pressed space key");
    }
};

myJPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "pressedLeft");
myJPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "pressedLeft");
myJPanel.getActionMap().put("pressedLeft", left);

myJPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "pressedRight");
myJPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "pressedRight");
myJPanel.getActionMap().put("pressedRight", right);

myJPanel.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "pressedSpace");
myJPanel.getActionMap().put("pressedSpace", space);
```

Everything works perfectly, but i noticed that when i press i.e. <kbd>SPACE</kbd> while holding <kbd>A</kbd>, the `left` action isn't fired anymore, it would be great if events for both pressed keys are fired.

Is there any way to use key bindings with key combinations?

Answer (score 2):

See [Motion Using the KeyBoard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a potential solution.

An event is only generated for the last key pressed so you need to manually keep track of any other keys that have been pressed (and keep manually simulate firing the event). This is true whether you use key bindings or a KeyListener.